# How to copy data from plotly table?

Tags: python, plotly

I have created a table using plotly

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
        go.Table(
            header=dict(
                values=["<b>Fixed Cost</b>", "<b>Variable Cost</b>", "<b>Start Up Cost</b>", "<b>Shut Down Cost</b>",
                        "<b>Total Cost</b>", "<b>Exports</b>"],
                font=dict(size=16),
                align="center",
                height=40
            ),
            cells=dict(
                values=[np.random.randint(10, 50, 5),
np.random.randint(10, 50, 5),
np.random.randint(10, 50, 5),
np.random.randint(10, 50, 5),
np.random.randint(10, 50, 5),
np.random.randint(10, 50, 5),
                        ],
                align=["center", "center"],
                font=dict(size=16),
                height=40
            )
        )
    )
fig.update_layout(font=dict(size=14),autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=1000,
    )

fig.update_layout(font=dict(size=14),autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=1000,
    )

fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

When I see this table on Html and try to copy the data from the table to notepad or anywhere else then I can't copy any of these values. In plotly, do we have any way to copy the data from that Html table?